# Django Pipeline not compiling .eco files

Tags: django, spine.js

Today after reinstalling all of my Python libraries, I noticed none of my .eco files were being compiled by Pipeline, even though Django Spine's `EcoCompiler` class's `compile_file` was being called for each .eco file.

Why aren't any compiled .eco files (output as .js files) being written?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Django Spine](https://github.com/ikeikeikeike/django-spine) 0.3.2 (as of this writing) expects an older-than-current version of [Pipeline](https://github.com/cyberdelia/django-pipeline) (current: 1.2.13, necessary for Django Spine 0.3.2: 1.2.10) which actually writes compiled files to the hard drive itself:

From `pipeline.compilers.__init__` version 1.2.10, lines 36 – 38:

```
content = self.read_file(path)
compiled_content = compiler.compile_file(content, finders.find(path))
self.save_file(new_path, compiled_content)
```

Compare with `pipeline.compilers.__init__` version 1.2.13, line 38:

```
compiler.compile_file(infile, outfile, outdated=outdated, force=force)
```

Notice how `compile_file` is called with very different arguments. If you check the [current source](https://github.com/cyberdelia/django-pipeline/blob/master/pipeline/compressors/__init__.py), you'll notice pipeline doesn't call `save_file` at all!

Anyway, just do this until django-spine & django-pipeline align on this issue:

```
pip uninstall django-pipeline
pip install django-pipeline==1.2.10
```

Comment: I submitted a similar issue, but I'll delete mine since yours is more informative.